# Bluetooth mesh simulator

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, simulation, mesh-network

I am working on a project that involves Bluetooth Mesh Network (based on BLE) that was standardized with Bluetooth version 5.0. I am searching for a suitable simulator for at least some of the following solutions.

1. Mesh message delivery (Flooding)
2. Ability to simulate an environment (Path loss, multipath fading)

Can someone help me find a simulator as the one explained above?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best easy and cheap option is the nRF Mesh app for Android/iOS devices. It might not be advanced to do full simulation but you'll find most of what you need to get started and then you can tweak things or expand from there manually.

More information is available here:-

- [nRF Mesh app features](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Mesh)
- [The ultimate Bluetooth mesh tutorial (Part 5)](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-mesh-tutorial-part-5/)
- [A developer's guide for proving mesh interoperability](https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/proving-mesh-interoperability/)